# Hyperledger composer-cli install failing Mac OS

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Following a Hyperledger Dev course https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html

And ran the `npm install -g composer-cli` command on Mac OS. It doesn't seem like a permissions problem, I've had those before. This is the line that stands out to me from the log below;

`Failed at the grpc@1.10.1 install script.`

I am running NPM version 6.7.0 and Node version 11.10.0

`18655 silly install grpc@1.10.1
18656 info lifecycle grpc@1.10.1~install: grpc@1.10.1
18657 verbose lifecycle grpc@1.10.1~install: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
18658 verbose lifecycle grpc@1.10.1~install: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/usr/local:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
18659 verbose lifecycle grpc@1.10.1~install: CWD: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc
18660 silly lifecycle grpc@1.10.1~install: Args: [ '-c',
18660 silly lifecycle   'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library' ]
18661 silly lifecycle grpc@1.10.1~install: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
18662 info lifecycle grpc@1.10.1~install: Failed to exec install script
18663 timing action:install Completed in 40426ms
18664 verbose unlock done using /Users/mu/.npm/_locks/staging-3a08f0df5026584d.lock for /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging
18665 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1847ms
18666 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 62690ms
18667 verbose stack Error: grpc@1.10.1 install:`node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
`18667 verbose stack Exit status 1
18667 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
18667 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:197:13)
18667 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
18667 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
18667 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:984:16)
18667 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
18668 verbose pkgid grpc@1.10.1
18669 verbose cwd /Users/mu/Documents/Hyperledger
18670 verbose Darwin 18.2.0
18671 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.10.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "composer-cli"
18672 verbose node v11.10.0
18673 verbose npm  v6.7.0
18674 error code ELIFECYCLE
18675 error errno 1
18676 error grpc@1.10.1 install:`node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
`18676 error Exit status 1
18677 error Failed at the grpc@1.10.1 install script.
18677 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
18678 verbose exit [ 1, true ]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [failed to install composer-cli but I see errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075445/failed-to-install-composer-cli-but-i-see-errors)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use node version 8.9 or higher but 9 or higher than that arenot supported and npm 5.x. It is clearly specified in [pre-requisities section](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs)