# Unable to install composer rest server

Tags: node.js, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to install composer rest server in my macOS and im getting errors. How do I resolve these errors and install composer rest server ?

I was reading [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-a-blockchain-network-using-hyperledger-fabric-and-composer-e06644ff801d) article and learning how to implement Composer Blockchain network.
When I run

> npm install -g composer-rest-server

I'm getting following error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/pc/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:160:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/pc/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/bin/node" "/Users/pc/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/pc/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/pkcs11js
gyp ERR! node -v v9.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pkcs11js@1.0.17 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pkcs11js@1.0.17 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/pc/.npm/_logs/2019-05-10T06_00_02_075Z-debug.log
```

My node version 9.4.0
 npm version 5.6.0

Is it compulsory to install xcode to run this code ? Please tell the significance of xcode to run composer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue occurred because `node v9.x.x` is not supported by `hyperledger composer tools`.

So, you have to use **`node v8.x.x`**.

Steps: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075445/failed-to-install-composer-cli-but-i-see-errors/53077670#53077670)

Also install `Xcode Command Line Tools`.

Steps: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-install-command-line-tools)

Comment: Is it compulsory to install xcode to run composer ? Or Could you tell in your answwer what is the significance of xcode in installling composer ?

Comment: I also would like to know how to install composer in latest node version.

Comment: It is not compulsory to install full `xcode` , it requires only cli tools to build composer tools. For `windows` you need to install `windows-build-tools` & same for `ubuntu` you need to install `build-essential`.